# How can I see the white balance levels of photos in playback with my Nikon DSLR?

Tags: nikon, white-balance, image-review

I am a Nikon user, and have recently moved to the Nikon D5100.

On my old camera when viewing images I would be able to press the arrow button and I would be able to see the white balance levels of the image. I cannot figure out how to do this on the D5100. How do I do it?

Comment: Do you mean by "white balance levels" the RGB histogram?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to see the white balance setting, then in the playback menu, find the playback display options and enable "shooting data" which will include aperture, shutter speed, white balance and other settings.

The playback display options also include an option to show the RGB histogram, if that's what you mean.

Once enabled, you can cycle through the displays using up/down arrows.